# Domain of the function $\sqrt{-3x^2-5x+8}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, quadratics

This might be a silly question to ask but I encountered a problem during solving this question. The question says to find the domain of $f(x) = \sqrt{-3x^2-5x+8}$. For the function $f(x)$ to have real values, the quantity $-3x^2-5x+8 \ge 0$.
$$
-3x^2+3x-8x+8 \ge 0 \\ 
3x(-x+1)+8(-x+1) \ge 0 \\
(3x+8)(-x+1) \ge 0 \\
x \ge \frac{-8}{3} \quad \text{or}\quad x\le 1
$$
Well, the domain of the is calculated to be $[\frac{-8}{3},1]$. Plotting the function on [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqW7P.png), we can be further be assured that the domain I have calculated is correct. But, when I tried solving this again and encountered exactly opposite domain.

$$
-3x^2+3x-8x+8 \ge 0 \\ 
-3x(x-1)-8(x-1) \ge 0 \\
(-3x-8)(x-1) \ge 0 \\
x \le \frac{-8}{3} \quad \text{or}\quad x\ge 1
$$

During the second process, I took $-3x$ and $-8$ as common factor. After that, I simplified and got the domain of the function to be $(-\infty, \frac{-8}{3}] \cup [1,\infty)$. I got two different answers just by changing the factor to negative. I think I am missing something crucial here and making a mistake. Please help me find the reason what and why am I doing wrong.

Comment: Every real number is either $\geq -8/3$ or $\leq 1,$ so this can't be right.

Comment: Can you please explain what is wrong?

Comment: I simply did, $x-1 \ge 0$ and added 1 on the both side to get $x \ge 1$. Similarly, $3x-8 \ge 0$ and added $8$ to both sides and divided by $-3$.

Comment: The end of your 1st method is wrong: $(3x+8)(-x+1) \ge 0$ iff $3x+8$ and $-x+1$ are both $\ge0$ (they cannot be both $\le0$), i.e. iff $-3/8\le x\le1.$ There shouldn't be an "or" in your resolution. Analogous mistakes in your second method.

Comment: @AnneBauval Ok, I get it that both $(3x+8)$ and $(-x+1) \ge 0$. But, can't $(3x+8)$ and $(-x+1)$ be negative so they become greater than zero. I didn't understand why you said they cannot be both less then or equal to zero.

Comment: They can't because it would imply $1\le x\le-8/3.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that Dom($f)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}~|~-3x^2-5x+8\ge 0\}$, where $f(x)=-3x^2-5x+8$.
Now, $-3x^2-5x+8\ge 0\iff (3x+8)(x-1)\le 0\iff 3x+8 \text{ and }x-1 \text{ have different signs}$. So it is enough to investigate the following two possibilities: 
(i) $3x+8\ge 0$ and $x-1\le 0$, i.e., $x\in\left[-\frac{8}{3},1\right]$, or
(ii) $3x+8\le 0$ and $x-1\ge 0$, which is of course absurd.

Thus Dom($f$)=$\left[-\frac{8}{3},1\right]$.

Comment: This might be really stupid but can you please explain "$3x+8\le 0$ and $x-1\ge 0$, which is of course absurd."  How do I know that the result I got is absurd?

Comment: $3x+8\le 0$ means $x\le -\frac{8}{3}$ and $x-1\ge 0$ means $x\ge 1$. These two cannot occur simultaneously.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome.